# Laravel : Storing navigation in cache but want to set active class based on current url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel for a CMS Application, I have stored the navigation menu in Cache, Since It's generated dynamically from the database and every time the navigation menu is updated in Database, The cache will be updated as well.

The only issue i have is, Though i can access the navigation menu easily, I want to set active class on the link of the page being accessed and this is really driving me mad.

This is how i have stored the nav in cache

```
<a href="www.dev.com/home" class="<?php Request::is('home*') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Home</a>
<a href="www.dev.com/about-us" class="<?php Request::is('about-us*') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">About Us</a>
<a href="www.dev.com/services" class="<?php Request::is('services*') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Services</a>
```

And this is how i access the navigation within the `page.blade.php` file
`{{ Navigation::display_main_menu() }}`, This function checks whether a cache exists or not, If not then it creates the cache and then returns the value.

But the navigation gets displayed exactly like this `with php tags` and not with the class (which i want to see), I even tried changing how i store nav to `<a href="www.dev.com/home" class="{{ Request::is('home*') ? 'active' : '' }}">Home</a>` but even this gets displayed exactly as it is.

What can i do to execute the `php` code or the `blade` syntax when the navigation is being rendered.

Please point me in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may `add` a new `macro` in `HTML` class, simply add this in a file (`macros.php`) and store it inside `app/start` directory then include it from the `app/startglobal.php` file using `require/include`:

```
HTML::macro('menuItem', function($name, $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array()){
    $currentUrl = URL::current() == url() ? url('home') : URL::current();
    $active = ( $currentUrl == URL::route($name, $parameters) ) ? ' class="active"':'';
    return '<li'.$active.'>' . HTML::linkRoute($name, $title, $parameters, $attributes) . '</li>';
});
```

In your `view` you may generate the menu items using something like this:

```
<ul>
    {{ HTML::menuItem('page.home', 'Home', array('home')) }}
</ul>
```

Here `page.home` is the route name assigned to `/` when declaring the `route` and yes in this case routes should have `name`, for example:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'PageController@home', 'as' => 'page.home'));
```

In the `menuItem` macro the second parameter (`Home`) is the menu title to show and the third parameter is an optional parameter if has any. So for example, your `About Us` page has the parameter `about-us` and to create the menu item you may use this:

```
{{ HTML::menuItem('page.about', 'About Us', array('about-us')) }}
```

This is a possible solution and there may be other ways.